# How to rotate DocumentClient keys when it is a singleton?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I seem to have two contradictory requirements.

Firstly I am injecting a DocumentClient into various document stores I'm using, and that DocumentClient should be a singleton:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-1-2/

Secondly I need to be able to rotate the keys in the Azure Portal.

But, DocumentClient is constructed with an endpoint and either the Primary Key or the Secondary Key.

So if the keys are rotated I cannot "update" DocumentClient as it's a singleton.  Obviously restarting the application will work, but I wanted to avoid the requirement to do that.

So, any thoughts on how to achieve both?  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Usually key rotation is two step process.

Step #1 Rotate one of the key(either primary or secondary) which is not actively used by the application.

Step #2 Publish the new key to the application as part of your application rollout.